# Jquery tablesort

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using tablesorter for jquery and using this page as example

http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers.html

and using this plugin:

http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js

this is the code to sort "status"

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
      id: 'status',
      is: function(s) {
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected
        return false;
      },
      format: function(s, table, cell, cellIndex) {
        // format your data for normalization
        //console.log(cellIndex);
        return s.toLowerCase()
          .replace(/Deleted/,4)
          .replace(/Finished/,3)
          .replace(/Cancelled/,2)
          .replace(/In Progress/,1)
          .replace(/New/,0);
      },
      // set type, either numeric or text
      type: 'numeric'
    });

$('#request').tablesorter(
        {
            debug:false, 
            widthFixed: false,
            headers: {
                0: { sorter: false },
                3: { sorter: false },
                4: { sorter: 'dates-desired' },
                6: { sorter: 'dates-projected' },
                7: { sorter: 'status' },
                8: { sorter: false },
            }
        }
    );
```

But when i click the status thead, nothing happens

when i make the debug option: true, this is the o/p:

> "Sorting on 7,0 and dir 0 time (1ms)" jquery.tablesorter.min.js:157:5
>
> "Rebuilt table (4ms)" jquery.tablesorter.min.js:157:5 "Completed
>
> applying 0 widgets (0ms)"

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in within the parser code... the text is set to lower case, but the regex contains upper case characters. Try this updated parser:

```
var arry = [ 'new', 'in progress', 'cancelled', 'finished', 'deleted' ];
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'status',
    is: function() {
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected
        return false;
    },
    format: function( s, table, cell, cellIndex ) {
        var str = ( s || '' ).toLowerCase(),
            index = arry.indexOf( str );
        // return original text if index not found; this allows proper
        // sorting of empty cells
        return index < 0 ? s : index;
    },
    // set type, either numeric or text
    type: 'numeric'
});
```

If you need to support older versions of IE, then change from using `indexOf` to [jQuery's `$.inArray()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
index = $.inArray( str, arry );
```